# AttributeError: __name__ while importing pandas in django

Tags: django, import, package, attributeerror

I have installed Django pandas but while importing in views.py it is throwing attribute error.
Could someone help me out?

[error snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HD0SU.png)

Comment: Could you add the code snippet you're using in your views? From just your Traceback, I'm not seeing any reference to pandas package, so the problem might be something else (maybe not, I don't know, I need more info so I can help you)

Comment: I encountered the same problem! wondering what happened..